# Properties of Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, linear-transformations, markov-chains

Consider the case of a Markov matrix $P$ which can act on probability measures $\mu$ (so that $P\mu$ is the distribution over states after a transition applied to an initial distribution $\mu$). **My interpretation of certain matrix properties are the following; please add more and correct me if I'm wrong:**

1. An **eigenvector** of $P$ is a distribution that is invariant under the transition $P$. Even if the corresponding eigenvalue is $<1$ (I know eigenvalues of $P$ are at most $1$, and $1$ is always an eigenvalue), the eigenvector has to be normalized since it's a probability measure, so it is invariant. Is that right?
2. **Diagonalizability** means the matrix is full-rank. Does this mean that all states are accessible from all others, i.e. the Markov chain is irreducible? What does a Jordan form correspond to? If this previous intuition is right, the blocks may correspond to the equivalence classes of states accessible from each other?
3. **Determinant** is usually interpreted geometrically as the volume of the parallelopiped resulting from the linear transformation by $P$ on the unit cube. How can we interpret this in the Markov matrix setting?

More questions,

1. How can we interpret **operations** on rows that give diagonal form (Gaussian-elimination type operations like adding a multiple of a row to another)?
2. What does **(a)periodicity** show up as in a Markov matrix?
3. What does it mean when basis vectors are **orthogonal**?

What other parallels are there?

Comment: (1) eigenvectors of P in general are not probability distributions as they will in general have mixed signs. (2) Diagonalizability of a matrix has *nothing to do with the markov matrix being full-rank*; any questions about Jordan Forms are way outside the scope if you don't understand the error here.  (3) Periodicity of a markov matrix has to do with how many distinct eigenvalues it has on the unit circle.  My sense is you need to go through a book on linear algebra to learn fundamentals relating to eigen-stuff and orthogonality